# ActiveMQ persistence issue while using REST

Tags: rest, activemq-classic

I'm using default ActiveMQ (version 5.10.0) configuration which is supposed to persist the messages to the disk.

When I publish some messages on a topic, shutdown the activemq, restart it again and then start the consumer, the consumer does not receive the messages.

here is a detailed description.

1. I subscribe a consumer on a topic X using REST interface.
2. I publish a message on a topic X using REST
3. I shutdown ActiveMQ and then restart it.
4. I start a consumer to receive a message on topic X. Nothing is received.

So, what happened with the message I sent?

the command I use for publishing:

`curl -u admin:admin -d "body=test" "http://localhost:8161/api/message/erdata" -d type=topic`

the command for subscribing:

`wget --user admin --password admin --save-cookies cookies.txt --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies "http://localhost:8161/api/message/erdata?type=topic&clientId=consumer"`

**UPDATE**

Based on Erik's answer I've tried using virtual topics. 
I've added to activemq.xml the following code:

```
<destinationInterceptors>
      <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
        <virtualDestinations>
          <virtualTopic name=">" prefix="VirtualTopicConsumers.*." selectorAware="false"/>
        </virtualDestinations>
      </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
    </destinationInterceptors>
```

I've also changed my commands for publishing and consuming.

The new command for publishing:

```
curl -u admin:admin -d "body=val1" "http://localhost:8161/api/message/VirtualTopic/erdata" -d type=topic
```

the new command for consuming:

```
wget --user admin --password admin --save-cookies cookies.txt --load-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies "http://localhost:8161/api/message/Consumer/A/VirtualTopic/erdata?type=queue&clientId=A"
```

The problem now is that I don't even receive any messages in the consumer. hawtio tells me that I have a topic VirtualTopic.erdata where there are 0 consumers, 4 messages are enqueued and there are 0 dequeued and 0 dispatched messages. There is a queue Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.erdata that has 1 consumer but there are 0 enqueued, dispatched and dequeued messages. What am I doing wrong here?

Gregor

Answer (score 0):

Topics do not support persistence without durable subscriptions, or one of the topic to queue solutions, such as virtual topics.  However  the REST API does not support durable subscriptions, 
so you are left with couple of options.

If you require that multiple subscribers get a copy of the message, and ensure the message survives an outage, you can use [Virtual Topics and/or Composite queues](http://activemq.apache.org/virtual-destinations.html).

However, if you only care that the next consumer gets the message then you can put straight to a queue simply by specifying "queue" as the type in your example above:

```
curl -u admin:admin -d "body=test" "http://localhost:8161/api/message/erdata" -d type=queue
```

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your answer. I tried it and now I don't get any messages in my topic subscriptions. I've written my changes in the updated question above - can you tell me where my mistake is?

Comment: Look at the queue name created vs the URL you are using.  Consumer/A/VirtualTopic/erdata created a queue called Consumer.A.VirtualTopic.erdata.  If you change this to VirtualTopic/erdata then you will be listening to the same queue that the messages are being persisted to.   With that copy and paste VT you set up, all topics will copy a message to queues that start with VirtualTopic.  Read the documentation for more detail.